# (PyQt) QTreeView - want to expand/collapse all children and grandchildren

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtreeview

I want to be able to expand or collapse all children of a particular branch in a QTreeView. I am using PyQt4.

I know that QTreeView's have an expand all children feature that is bound to *, but I need two things: It needs to be bound to a different key combination (shift-space) and I also need to be able to collapse all children as well.

Here is what I have tried so far:
I have a subclass of a QTreeView wherein I am checking for the shift-space key combo.  I know that QModelIndex will let me pick a specific child with the "child" function, but that requires knowing the number of children.  I *am* able to get a count of the children by looking at the internalPointer, but that only gives me info for the first level of the hierarchy. If I try to use recursion, I can get a bunch of child counts, but then I am lost as to how to get these converted back into a valid QModelIndex.

Here is some code:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    """
    Capture key press events to handle:
    - enable/disable
    """
    #shift - space means toggle expanded/collapsed for all children
    if (event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Space and 
        event.modifiers() & QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier):
        expanded = self.isExpanded(self.selectedIndexes()[0])
        for cellIndex in self.selectedIndexes():
            if cellIndex.column() == 0: #only need to call it once per row
                #I can get the actual object represented here
                item = cellIndex.internalPointer()
                #and I can get the number of children from that
                numChildren = item.get_child_count()
                #but now what? How do I convert this number into valid
                #QModelIndex objects? I know I could use: 
                #   cellIndex.child(row, 0)
                #to get the immediate children's QModelIndex's, but how
                #would I deal with grandchildren, great grandchildren, etc...
                self.setExpanded(cellIndex, not(expanded))
        return
```

Here is the beginning of the recursion method I was investigating, but I get stuck when actually trying to set the expanded state because once inside the recursion, I lose "contact" with any valid QModelIndex...

```
def toggle_expanded(self, item, expand):
    """
    Toggles the children of item (recursively)
    """
    for row in range(0,item.get_child_count()):
        newItem = item.get_child_at_row(row)
        self.toggle_expanded(newItem, expand)
    #well... I'm stuck here because I'd like to toggle the expanded
    #setting of the "current" item, but I don't know how to convert
    #my pointer to the object represented in the tree view back into
    #a valid QModelIndex
    #self.setExpanded(?????, expand)   #<- What I'd like to run
    print "Setting", item.get_name(), "to", str(expand) #<- simple debug statement that indicates that the concept is valid
```

Thanks to all for taking the time to look at this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok... siblings did not actually get me to where I wanted to go.  I managed to get the code working as follows (and it seems like a decent implementation).  Kudos still to Prof.Ebral who got me going on the right track with the idea of siblings (turns out I needed to use QModelIndex.child(row, column) and iterate recursively from there).

Note that there is the following assumption in the code: It assumes that your underlying data store objects have the ability to report how many children they have (get_child_count() in my code).  If that is not the case, you will somehow have to get a child count differently... perhaps by just arbitrarily trying to get child indexes - using QModelIndex.child(row, col) - with an ever increasing row count till you get back an invalid index? - this is what Prof.Ebral suggested and I might still try that (It is just that I already have an easy way to get the child count by requesting it from my data store).

Also note that I actually expand/collpase each node at a different point in the recursion based on whether I am expanding or collapsing.  This is because, through trial and error, I discovered that animated tree views would stutter and pop if I just did it at one place in the code.  Now, by reversing the order in which I do it based on whether I am at the top level (i.e. the root of the branch I am affecting - not the root of the entire treeview) I get a nice smooth animation.  This is documented below.

The following code is in a QTreeView subclass.

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
def keyPressEvent(self, event):

    if (event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Space and self.currentIndex().column() == 0):
        shift = event.modifiers() & QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier
        if shift:
            self.expand_all(self.currentIndex())
        else:                
            expand = not(self.isExpanded(self.currentIndex()))
            self.setExpanded(self.currentIndex(), expand)


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
def expand_all(self, index):
    """
    Expands/collapses all the children and grandchildren etc. of index.
    """
    expand = not(self.isExpanded(index))
    if not expand: #if collapsing, do that first (wonky animation otherwise)
        self.setExpanded(index, expand)    
    childCount = index.internalPointer().get_child_count()
    self.recursive_expand(index, childCount, expand)
    if expand: #if expanding, do that last (wonky animation otherwise)
        self.setExpanded(index, expand)


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
def recursive_expand(self, index, childCount, expand):
    """
    Recursively expands/collpases all the children of index.
    """
    for childNo in range(0, childCount):
        childIndex = index.child(childNo, 0)
        if expand: #if expanding, do that first (wonky animation otherwise)
            self.setExpanded(childIndex, expand)
        subChildCount = childIndex.internalPointer().get_child_count()
        if subChildCount > 0:
            self.recursive_expand(childIndex, subChildCount, expand)
        if not expand: #if collapsing, do it last (wonky animation otherwise)
            self.setExpanded(childIndex, expand)
```

Answer (score 2):

model.rowCount(index) is the method you want.

```
model = index.model()   # or some other way of getting it
for i in xrange(model.rowCount(index)):
  child = model.index(i,0, index)
  # do something with child
```

model.index(row,col, parent) is essentially the same as calling index.child(row,col); just with fewer indirections.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I would recommend using a QTreeWidget which inherits QTreeView. You can then grab the children as a QTreeWidgetItem.</strike>

Since you do not want to use the QTreeWidget but want to stick to your current model .. you can iterate through the 'possible' children using, .isValid(). You should not use the internalPointer() though. Instead use the cellItem you have, as it is the original ModalIndex .. then attempt to find it's siblings. Something like

```
x = 0; y =0
while cellIndex.sibling(x, y).isValid():
    child = cellIndex.sibling(x, y)
    x += 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am pretty committed to using the model/view framework, and as far as I know, I can't do that with the QTreeWidget, can I?

Comment: From the documentation --- The QTreeWidget class is a convenience class that provides a standard tree widget with a classic item-based interface similar to that used by the QListView class in Qt 3. This class is based on Qt's Model/View architecture and uses a default model to hold items, each of which is a QTreeWidgetItem.

Comment: But since I already have a model which does a lot of custom work, I still think I can't switch because the default model built into the QTreeWidget won't do any of the things I would need it to do.

Comment: Ok .. I'll take another look then.

Comment: Siblings! That might just be the thing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I make a evnetFilter Class for that.
My particular use case is shift click the drop indicator then expand all or collapse all the child nodes like software `maya` outliner.

```py
class MTreeExpandHook(QtCore.QObject):
    """
    MTreeExpandHook( QTreeView )
    """

    def __init__(self, tree):
        super(MTreeExpandHook, self).__init__()
        tree.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
        self.tree = tree

    def eventFilter(self, receiver, event):
        if (
            event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Type.MouseButtonPress
            and event.modifiers() & QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier
        ):
            pos = self.tree.mapFromGlobal(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
            index = self.tree.indexAt(pos)
            if not self.tree.isExpanded(index):
                self.tree.expandRecursively(index)
                return True
        return super(MTreeExpandHook, self).eventFilter(self.tree, event)
```

Usage Example below

```py
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore,QtGui,QtWidgets

class MTreeExpandHook(QtCore.QObject):
    """
    MTreeExpandHook( QTreeView )
    """

    def __init__(self, tree):
        super(MTreeExpandHook, self).__init__()
        self.setParent(tree)
        # NOTE viewport for click event listen
        tree.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
        self.tree = tree

    def eventFilter(self, receiver, event):
        if (
            # NOTE mouse left click 
            event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Type.MouseButtonPress
            # NOTE keyboard shift press
            and event.modifiers() & QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier
        ):
            # NOTE get mouse local position
            pos = self.tree.mapFromGlobal(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
            index = self.tree.indexAt(pos)
            if not self.tree.isExpanded(index):
                # NOTE expand all child
                self.tree.expandRecursively(index)
                return True
        return super(MTreeExpandHook, self).eventFilter(self.tree, event)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    
    # NOTE create nested data
    for i in range(3):
        parent = QtGui.QStandardItem('Family {}'.format(i))
        for j in range(3):
            child = QtGui.QStandardItem('Child {}'.format(i*3+j))
            for k in range(3):
                sub_child = QtGui.QStandardItem("Sub Child")
                child.appendRow([sub_child])
                for x in range(2):
                    sub_child_2 = QtGui.QStandardItem("Sub Child 2")
                    sub_child.appendRow([sub_child_2])
            parent.appendRow([child])
        model.appendRow(parent)

        
    treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
    treeView.setHeaderHidden(True)
    MTreeExpandHook(treeView)
    treeView.setModel(model)
    treeView.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[example gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuduK.gif)