# PyQt: current directory in QFileSystemModel

Tags: python, pyqt, qfilesystemmodel

I am using following code from some official example:

```
        model = QFileSystemModel()
        model.setRootPath(QDir.currentPath())
        view = QTreeView(parent=self);
        view.setModel(model)
```

I expected it to expand directory structure in the tree view so directory from which my program is run would be displayed. What I get, however, is unexpanded tree starting with file system root. How can I make it right?

I tried using `expand`, but it didn't help:

```
        model = QFileSystemModel()
        index = model.index(QDir.currentPath())
        view = QTreeView(parent=self);
        view.setModel(model)
        view.expand(index)
```

The tree view is still unexpanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use [QTreeView.expand](http://doc.trolltech.com/qtreeview.html#expand).

Comment: I tried to use expand, but it didn't help. Any idea why? I posted another snippet.

Comment: check recursive_expand in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100139/pyqt-qtreeview-want-to-expand-collapse-all-children-and-grandchildren/4208240#4208240

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed, that I have to expand recursively every step of the path. Thanks :-)